# Есть ли разница между char* a и char *a?

Tags: c, указатели, типы-данных, синтаксис

Будет ли разница между `char* a` и `char *a`?

```
int main(void)
{
   char S[max] = "Hello",
        S1[max] = "Привет";
   char *a = S;
   char* c = S1;
}
```

Я просто только начинаю разбираться в С и хотелось бы получше усвоить этот момент с указателями.

Comment: Абсолютно никакой.

Comment: как это никакой? а можно ещё и так написать `char * a` ?:) разница в предпочтениях и суевериях.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Абсолютно никакой. можете ставить пробелы где и сколько хотите.

Только учтите, что `*` относится к переменной, а не к `char`, так что

```
char* a, b;
```

это объявление переменной - указателя на `char` с именем `a` и переменной - просто `char` с именем `b`.

Comment: То есть синтаксически разницы нет, но вариант `char *a` иногда удобнее для читателя

Comment: Есть лишь стилистическая разница. Когда вам необходимо объявить два указателя, это будет выглядеть ```char *a, *b;``` или ```char* a, *b;```. Первый вариант выглядит приятнее

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, imho вариант `char     *a;` *всегда* удобней для читателя (даже если он сам автор кода)

Comment: А в C++ амперсанд и звёздочку прижимают к типу.

Comment: что бы не иметь проблем с такими штуками, лучше использовать typedef/using и все будет хорошо. Все таки звездочка (указатель) по всей логике, это свойство типа.

Answer (score 7):

Создатели языка задумывали синтаксис `char *a` (именно с таким расположением звездочки) как некоторую мнемонику: что выражение `*a` имеет тип `char`:

> For each object of such a composed type, there was already a way to mention the underlying object: index the array, call the function, use the indirection operator on the pointer. Analogical reasoning led to a declaration syntax for names mirroring that of the expression syntax in which the names typically appear. Thus,
>
> `int i, *pi, **ppi;`
>
> declare an integer, a pointer to an integer, a pointer to a pointer to an integer. The syntax of these declarations reflects the observation that `i`, `*pi`, and `**ppi` all yield an `int` type when used in an expression.
>
> *Dennis Ritchie — [The Development of the C Language](https://jslint.com/chistory.html)*

Еще больше эта задумка проявляется при объявлении нескольких переменных:

```c
int* foo, bar, ** baz;
```

В данном случае `foo` — это указатель на `int`, `bar` — просто `int`, `baz` — указатель на указатель на `int`. При использовании другого стиля это было бы более понятно:

```c
int *foo, bar, **baz;
```

Так что более предпочтительно было бы использовать стиль, где звездочка находится рядом с именем переменной. Если, конечно, это не противоречит style guide на вашем проекте.